# Execute batch script when mounting drive

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm currently using a container-based encryption tool, which provides the data through virtual drives on windows.

As I'm storing a program that I want to run every time the virtual drive is mounted (always same drive letter if that helps), I'm looking for a possibility that would enable me to run a small batch script that starts the program every time the drive is mounted (and hence available).

Is there a way to do this using Windows task scheduler?
Or do I have to write a program, to check if the particluar drive / script is available and execute it if so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an autorun.inf file in the root of the volume you're mounting.

```
open=program.exe
```

Where program.exe is the program you want to run. That's the easy part.

HOWEVER, this functionality is disabled on most newer versions of Windows. There are multiple ways to get around this.

1. It appears the easiest way is to install the program/utility APUSB 47 by Leelusoft. I must caution to make sure to check your install options carefully as it also tries to install some suspicious browser add-ons, but the program itself scans free and clear of malware and you can stop the add-ons from installing.

   Note that you must have good physical control of your system (no one else can come in and insert something like a usb drive to execute malware from), and know the source of your autorun.inf (e.g. you created it yourself) and what it calls because this could introduce a security risk.
2. Depending on your Windows version and settings, you can use the registry keys NoDriveTypeAutoRun or NoDriveAutoRun. I do have to warn that changing either of these from the Windows defaults **does introduce security risks**. If you have no security concern whatsoever, the easiest way is to simply delete both of these keys from both locations they might exist in:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
   ```

   and

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
   ```

   Likely there will only be one instance you have to delete, but unless your system is stand alone with no internet connections and no one but you has access to it, **I HIGHLY RECOMMEND AGAINST THIS METHOD.**

   **As an alternative**, since you know the drive letter of the device you're bringing online and assuming you have good control over direct access to this machine, you can use NoDriveAutoRun to ONLY allow autorun on the drive you're bringing online. This solution should be reasonably safe. Since I believe that's the safest option, I will present that here. You can search for specifics on the other methods if you'd like.

   To do this, first create a backup of your registry. Then, open up the registry editor, and go to this location:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
   ```

   If the key "NoDriveAutoRun" does not exist, create one of type REG_DWORD

   Now, for the value... here you have to exercise your binary/hex knowledge. Imagine 32 bits:

   ```
   00000011111111111111111111111111
   ```

   The first 6 are zeros, and each of the 26 1's represent a drive Z through A from left to right. If this value is set, Windows will not allow autorun on ANY drive. You want to enable on one drive. I don't know what drive letter it is, but let's just say it's drive F you want to enable. Then, you would have the following:

   ```
   00000011111111111111111111011111
   ```

   Now, you can't just enter the binary, you have to convert this to hex. Hopefully You have a calculator handy. If you have Windows 7 or earlier, you can use the built-in calculator with View/Programmer to do the conversion. If you have Windows 8, I'm sorry.

   In this case, this translates to

   ```
   0x3FFFFDF
   ```

   And that is the value you will enter for the registry key NoDriveAutoRun

   If the key "NoDriveTypeAutoRun" exists, delete it.

   Also check 
       HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

   For the key "NoDriveTypeAutoRun" and delete that if it exists.

Comment: I've tried decimal 62914559 (corresponding to drive letter W: (I hope)), but if I mount the drive (in TrueCrypt) the autorun won't execute no matter, if I choose to display as removable media or local drive. the key under current_user is empty (deleted the NoDriveTypeAutoRun) and I also deleted the other key correctly. Can it be that it doesn't work with TC's virtual drives?

Comment: That is the right decimal value, but I had thought it had to be entered in Hex, which would be 0x3BFFFFF

Comment: Are the only choices in TC "removable media" and "local drive"? Is there a way to specifically emulate "CD_ROM"? If so, try that.

Comment: you can use both, as there is a radio button on the right of the input field (hex and dec). And yes, the only choices are "local drive" and "removable media".

Comment: Make sure you don't have the following registry key in place: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping\Autorun.inf   If it's there, delete it.

Comment: there is no such value in this key entry :(

Comment: Which version of Windows are you running?

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

Comment: One other thing to try: run gpedit.msc (group policy editor), go to Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Autoplay Policies. Double-click Turn off Autoplay and make sure that it is set to disabled, double click on Default behavior for Autorun, set it to Enabled and then select Automatically execute the autorun commands.

Comment: OK, this will be my last comment. There's freeware available called APUSB 47, latest version I can find is 1.2. Give that a try. After that, I'm out of ideas. I'm not familiar specifically with TrueCrypt, hopefully someone else will come along that is if that's the source of your issue.

Comment: this entry does not exist in my gpedit :-( (HP isn't designed for active domains -> no gpedit.msc by default :-( )

Comment: THANK YOU TRASHMAN!!! with the tool APUSB 47 and my autorun.inf and the registry changes and some modifications to my .bat script and a small self-written relay .exe it's now working as expected! You might want to update your answer so other with similar questions will get the answer easier. Note: APUSB only accepts .exe files as target for open=, APUSB executes them in its own directory (so a initial cd is needed) and on installation it tried to download malware which was blocked by Kaspersky.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the scheduler and  [SCHTASKS](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) `/RI ONEVENT` switch (available from vista and above) - you'll need elevetated permissions.It will activate a task on a certain event , but you need to check your event log for the exact even when the drive is mounted([google search gave me this](http://www.swiftforensics.com/2012/08/tracking-usb-first-insertion-in-event.html) but anyway you'll need to check your events).